# How to get the number of commits between 2 git tags using octokit.net?

Tags: .net, octokit

I want to be able to get the total number of commits in a github repository between 2 git tags using [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) (Github .NET API).

Same as what the [compare](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/compare/4.0.0...4.0.1) in github does.

Comment: I'm not an octokit user, so can't help (although I played a bit tonight and couldn't find anything). Perhaps you'll get more activity if you provide information about what you've tried (if anything) and what worked and what didn't. I wasn't even able to find a [compare](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/search?q=Compare&ref=cmdform) API that used SHAs or already-found commit objects. I fear there may be no way, and that the best course would be to raise an issue. But again, I've only done a shallow search, and could be off base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not currently.

Longer answer: The GitHub API exposes the compare view here:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits

So you can call it like this and get the data you need:

`https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.net/compare/master...my-cool-branch`

If you can wait a little longer, I've started a pull request to officially support this in Octokit.net:

https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/pull/428

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I can wait